# Alternate Couchbase UI

Tags: user-interface, couchbase

Does anybody know if are there any alternative Couchbase user interfaces other than the official one provided when installing Couchbase ?

I'm looking for something like PhpMyAdmin for MySQL, which does **NOT** have to look like it or to have the same functionalities but to be open source and be different than the default one.

Comment: What's wrong with the built in interface? "Find me a tool" type questions are generally closed on StackOverflow.

Comment: There is nothing wrong. I just wanted to know if there are some alternatives and I've put this question here because I could not find anything when searching on google. My assumption is that there is no alternative (it would have jumped out right away  when google-ing) but there might have been 1% chances that some alternatives existed though  and google could not have been able to find related usefull content in its database.

Comment: It's a very sophisticated UI already for a commercial product that has a lot of functionality built in. It would be a tremendous amount of effort to build something that meets and exceeds the existing functionality. Low gain with high pain. :)

Comment: What's wrong with the built in interface is that you cannot edit or preview any documents larger than 2.5k.  This is quite frustrating with large docs.

Comment: @WiredPrairie What's wrong with that? The limitations are annoying. You can't create a document that consists of an array (which is totally fine to do with the api); Every time you switch to the Documents view it shows only 5 documents (by default); You can't edit documents larger than 2.5k (unless you fiddle with documents.js in dev tools); You can't delete multiple documents at once; You can't see document IDs longer than 16 characters, etc.

Comment: Browser UI only shows documents with a size less than 2.5 kb. If your document is biger, you need another mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchbase default web interface provides almost all functions that are needed to administrate database: create databases (aka buckets), create documents, edit documents, edit and test views. It can't provide "same functionalities" as phpmyadmin because couchbase belongs to different database class...

Also couchbase is opensource, so you can download or fork couchbase sources and add/edit whatever you want into standard web interface.

Comment: mysql has its database explorer and yet PhpMyAdmin exists for it as an alternative. I know couchbase interface but i wanted to find out if there may be another UI tool than the one provided. Though, nothing is wrong with Couchbase factory UI tool . Unfortunately i cannot accept this answer because it does not answers my initial question.

Comment: Couchbase has it's "database explorer", even two "explorers". They are located in "Data Buckets" tab on the right side of your bucket. Buttons that navigate to that "explorers" are called "Documants" (that "explorers" documents that are stored in database) and "Views" (that allows you to explore,create,delete, etc. views stored in database). I have a question for you: Do you know how couchbase works "under the hood": stores documents, operates with them, etc.?

Comment: I apreciate your answers but i have to repeat that my question was about if there are some alternatives. I know how to use Couchbase explorer and i know that CRUD operations are done via http requests (REST API). The default factory UI has all necessary tools to manipulate the database behind.

Comment: But, what if I want to explore a remote  Couchbase server where i do not have access to the UI tool but I am able (permitted) to make REST requests on it? I need a remote Couchbase explorer where i can config the host, the user, the password and use it as a it would be an explorer for a local installation. I will accept your answer if no other answers will arrive in the very near future.

Comment: To make REST queries to couchabse you need http client (i.e. web-browser) that can access remote server on `8092` port. To use couchbase UI you need the same: web-browser and access to `8091`. So it's hard to imagine the situation you've described. But couchbase also has powerfull command-line tool that can be used on local machine to access to remote machine and this tool has even more options than web ui. Also you can write your own small app that will use couchbase API library. But in all situations you will need to be able to access remote machine on 8091 port.

Comment: Quote: "Also you can write your own small app that will use couchbase API library". Exactly this is why i wanted to know if there are alternative Couchbase UI explorers. To avoid making my own small app but to use an already existent one. Anyways I think I'll have to do my own app to explore remote Couchbase DB where I have  (only) REST access but no UI. Which I know it seems weird but this is how the things are setup in my case.

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a DML like tool for retrieving docs from couchbase, this tool works pretty good. 
https://github.com/rrutt/cb-bread

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer that doesn't amount to: "You don't need one" or "Build one yourself" ;-)